# Ricci flow + Nash embedding

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, flows

I have a basic question about how geometric flows such as the Ricci flow interact with the Nash embedding theorem.

Say you have a 1-parameter family of Riemann metrics on a compact  manifold $N$.  If it helps, make it Ricci flow.

The Nash embedding theorem states that any of these Riemann manifolds embed in a fairly high-dimensional Euclidean space.

Can you guarantee that there is a smooth family of Riemann embeddings, i.e. smoothly lift the entire 1-parameter family?

I am concerned with the most basic case, i.e. where the flow of the metric is smooth.  One could think of the metrics as a smooth fibrewise family of metrics on $N \times I$ (over $I$) so no singularities or complicating issues.

My presumption is the answer to this question is known (and yes), and it  likely follows from Nash's original proof.  But I have not thought about that in many years and have not come across a claim such as this.

Comment: I think there is one simple case that follows from Alexandrov's theorem. If you have a compact surface whose curvature is positive (at the initial time), then the curvature will be positive for all time afterwards and so Alexandrov's theorem should give a unique embedding of the surface into $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since this embedding is unique, I'm fairly sure it has to be continuous, but I'm not familiar with the estimates off-hand to say for sure.

Comment: @GabeK, the flow of embeddings has to be smooth, because the derivatives of the embedding with respect to both time and space themselves satisfy a PDE obtained by differentiating the isometric embedding system. Another (equivalent) way to see this is to observe that the solution is obtained using the implicit function theorem, and the standard proof shows that the resulting map depends smoothly on parameters in the original equation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One can get it as a corollary of the embedding theorem.
So, you do not need to read the proof if you trust Nash.

Choose a metric $g$ on $N\times I$ so that the induced metric on the slice $N\times {t}$ is your metric $g_t$.
(You may think that slices are orthogonal to the curves $\{p\}\times I$ if needed.)
Now apply Nash's theorem to the product.

Comment: Right, that works, although it's a little more heavy-handed than I'd like. Presumably you could get a better dimension estimate by thinking of it only as a family of Riemann metrics on the fibers.   But you've answered my  question as asked, thanks.

Comment: Given the Nash embedding $f : N \times I \to \mathbb R^k$ for the Ricci flow, my presumption is we don't have a concrete expression for the differential equation satisfied by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$?  i.e. this is the motion corresponding to the Ricci flow.  Presumably there should be some "motion" version of the  Ricci flow.

Comment: @RyanBudney yes, from the proof you should get better dimension, it should be the same dimension as for the embedding. It would be nice to have a "motion version" of such embedding --- then you could start with a nice embedding of the standard sphere and follow the solution of Ricci flow backwords to get a nice (in which sense?) embedding of a given 3 manifold.

Comment: First, I don't see the point of a "better" dimension unless you have a sharp value of the dimension fo ther initial embedding. Otherwise, the dimension given by Nash and others is quite far from optimal. Second, the equation satisfied by $\partial_tf$ can be inferred from the formula used to invert the linearization of the isometric embedding PDE. The linearization is highly underdetermined, so there are many ways to invert it. To get a reasonable PDE, you want to choose the linearization carefully. Probably Gunther's is a good one, but the equation won't be a PDE.